# Autoplay without users action

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode6, swift2

Have been searching a lot for how to autoplay a video on for example Youtube,  within my app, WITHOUT the users action. Meaning without having to manually push the play button.

Find a lot of old topics, where its mentioned that this is not possible.

Found also this: "In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it. This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the play() or load() method is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play button works, but an onLoad="play()" event does not."

These are old posts, but is this still valid ??

In Swift in my web view property, there is this checkbox that I can tick off called "Playback requires user action".

I really need my app to autoplay videos.... is there any way around this ?

What if I instead only needed audio from a website to be played without users action..... would it then be possible somehow ??

ANY help, would be highly appreciated.

Ola

Comment: You can trigger UIWebView actions with Javascript. This link has some basics http://blog.impathic.com/post/64171814244/true-javascript-uiwebview-integration-in-ios7. You can test UI with Javascript - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009771, so I know what you're trying is possible. I don't know the wrapper code to use with Swift though. I have done this in Objective C.

Comment: One more link with some info on using with Swift http://sourcefreeze.com/uiwebview-example-using-swift-in-ios/

Comment: Thanks so much for helping noobsmcgoobs ! :-)                                    I'm a newbee, so this is a little above my knowledge :(                         But Your saying that You have done this in Objective C and got it working ? :-)                                                                                                Is there anyway, that You could show me the code for this in Objective C ??

Comment: I don't have the code anymore. Just look at those tutorials and you should be able to figure it out in 5 minutes.